# All remote access applications are intermittently seizing

Tags: windows-10, remote-access, remote-control

When I use a remote desktop application, such as TeamViewer, AnyDesk or Splashtop, to connect to my work computer, I keep experiencing intermittent freezing. It runs normally for about 10 seconds, then freezes for about 5 seconds, then works normally again for 10 seconds, and so on and so on. I am running Windows 10 on both machines.

I know it is specific to one machine because my laptop does not experience the same issue connecting to the same work system over the same network. I have tried uninstalling Kaspersky, uninstalling a number of other programs that could have potentially been the problem and running a Windows system repair. I've kept an eye on CPU, memory and disk usage while the freezing has occurred but no processes stand out. There are no problems on my machine when online other than in remote desktop.

The problem also tends to disappear at night. I can usually figure these things out but I have no idea how to proceed at this point.

Has anyone encountered the same problem or have advice for next steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this issue, it looks like I finally found the problem, but only after a complete reinstall of Windows didn't fix the issue. I replaced my WiFi adapter and now there's no issue with remote access. Also looks like my internet connection is improved overall. So it turned out to be a hardware problem.